# OptaPlanner result is always empty

Tags: optaplanner

I have started to study Optaplanner since yesterday.
First, i have analyzed TSP problem provided in examples, created an empty Java project from scratch and rewrited all the code.

The concepts and documentation of OptaPlanner are (for the moment !) clear for me, but the **locationList** in TspSolution after solving is always empty.

I have read 10x the doc / code, and I become crazy !
Have you some ideas ? The insertion in list must be done manually in easy / increment score calculator ?

Thanks you very much, any help is welcome !

You will find an example if logs below.

```
START SOLVING !
INFO  Solving started: time spent (17), best score (-4init/0), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (46), best score (-6100), score calculation speed (227/sec), step total (4).
INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (5000), best score (-6100), score calculation speed (303348/sec), step total (1502180).
INFO  Solving ended: time spent (5000), best score (-6100), score calculation speed (300437/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
SOLVED !!!!
TspSolution{locationList=[], domicile=DOMICILE, visitList=[VISIT_01, VISIT_02, VISIT_03, VISIT_04], score=-6100}
```

Main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("START SOLVING !");

        // Build the Solver
     //   SolverFactory<TspSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("test.xml", TSPTest.class.getClassLoader());

        SolverFactory<TspSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createEmpty();
        SolverConfig solverConfig = solverFactory.getSolverConfig();
        ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig scanAnnotatedClassesConfig = new ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig();
        scanAnnotatedClassesConfig.setPackageIncludeList(Arrays.asList("com.coursierprive.streams.job.utils.tsp"));
        solverConfig.setScanAnnotatedClassesConfig(scanAnnotatedClassesConfig);


        ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig scoreDirectorFactoryConfig = new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig();
        // scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setEasyScoreCalculatorClass(CloudBalancingEasyScoreCalculator.class);
        scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setIncrementalScoreCalculatorClass(TspIncrementalScoreCalculator.class);
        scoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setInitializingScoreTrend("ONLY_DOWN");
        solverConfig.setScoreDirectorFactoryConfig(scoreDirectorFactoryConfig);

        TerminationConfig terminationConfig = new TerminationConfig();
        terminationConfig.setSecondsSpentLimit(5L);
        solverConfig.setTerminationConfig(terminationConfig);



        Solver<TspSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        TspSolution initialSolution = new TspSolution();


        initialSolution.setDomicile(new Domicile(new Location("DOMICILE", 42.0, 2.0)));
        initialSolution.getVisitList().add(new Visit("V1", new Location("VISIT_01", 42.0, 3.0)));
        initialSolution.getVisitList().add(new Visit("V2", new Location("VISIT_02", 43.0, 3.0)));
        initialSolution.getVisitList().add(new Visit("V3", new Location("VISIT_03", 44.0, 3.0)));
        initialSolution.getVisitList().add(new Visit("V4", new Location("VISIT_04", 45.0, 3.0)));


        // Solve the problem
        TspSolution optimizedSolution = solver.solve(initialSolution);


        System.out.println("SOLVED !!!!");

        System.out.println(optimizedSolution);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the examples, as implemented, adding a location to a `Visit` or `Docimicile` instance doesn't automatically add it to the solution's location list.

The reason that a solution has a location list in the first place, is to give pass those instances as problem facts into drools (if you're using such calculation). But the DRL score rules probably don't match Location anyway, so it may be unneeded for TspSolution to even have a locationList.

Comment: Hello, thank you Geoffrey for your response.

My god, the list of locations are simply optimized and re-ordonned !
The doc is clear but a little example will be welcome in future for a beginner in Opta Planner;)

I have seen some temporary variables are defined in solution in multiple example (such locations) are used by the swing UI. 

So it's a little confused when we start learning with examples.

Now, i can start the best part ;).